# writing an NSArray to plist works in simulator but fails in the device

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to save an NSArray to a plist, when i try it on the simulator, it works properly but if i run it on the device, it fails at writting. here is the code:

```
-(void)writePlist:(NSArray*)_newLevelAr{


    NSArray * levels = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_newLevelAr];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chapter%d",idChapter] ofType:@"plist"];

    if([levels writeToFile:path atomically: YES]){
        NSLog(@"write succesful");}
    else {
        NSLog(@"write failed");
    }

}
```

I suppose that something is wrong with the path but i'm not sure.

anyone knows why can be this happening? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to application bundle on device, you should write to Documents folder or Caches folder instead:

```
// Write file to docs folder
NSString* docFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * path = [docFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chapter%d.plist",idChapter]];
```

Comment: Thank you, but now how can i create the plist in that directory through the xCode?? because every time i read it, im reading the first created plist and that one is not changing. Thank you very much

Comment: Add initial plist as resource then on launch check if plist file is present in docs folder then read it, if it is not present then read the one, that's in application bundle resources